# SQL Query return only record set based on vaule

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am try to get a SQL query to return one set of values based on a a int value is set to 1

```
 Date           Name                Split         ID 
2014-09-02    Harry Potter         1            23
2014-09-02    Harry Potter         1            434
2014-09-02    Michael Jinks        0            24
2014-09-02    Sam Smith            1            12
2014-09-02    Sam Smith            1            244
2014-09-02    Kelly Jane           0            124
2014-09-03    Harry Potter         1            23
2014-09-03    Harry Potter         1            434
```

I want it to only return one value from each record that user taking Harry Potter if split is set to "1" then ignore the second record ID

It needs to be a if statement if Split = "1" then lookup up top record and return value but nothing i can find can do this.

i have  tried

```
select  distinct * from LOG where split = 1
```

should return something like this

```
Date           Name                Split         ID 
2014-09-02    Harry Potter         1            23
2014-09-02    Michael Jinks        0            24
2014-09-02    Sam Smith            1            12
2014-09-02    Kelly Jane           0            124
2014-09-03    Harry Potter         1            23
```

Comment: I think you want to use `SELECT DISTINCT` after filtering on `Split=1`

Comment: You should include the query you ran to output the above.

Comment: tried that will still return all the values as the ID are Distinct

Comment: Can you provide sample output?  What do *you* mean by record?  Normally, that would mean a row, but you don't return one value from a row (well, one column).

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
create table #temp(
    [date] smalldatetime,
    name varchar(100),
    split int,
    id int
)
insert into #temp
select '2014-09-02', 'Harry Potter', 1, 23 union all
select '2014-09-02', 'Harry Potter', 1, 434 union all
select '2014-09-02', 'Michael Jinks', 0, 24 union all
select '2014-09-02', 'Sam Smith', 1, 12 union all
select '2014-09-02', 'Sam Smith', 1, 244 union all
select '2014-09-02', 'Kelly Jane', 0, 124 union all
select '2014-09-03', 'Harry Potter', 1, 23 union all
select '2014-09-03', 'Harry Potter', 1, 434

-- Start
;with cte as(
    select
        *,
        row_number() over(partition by name order by [date], id) as rn -- For each name display first record with earliest date and lowest id
        --row_number() over(partition by name, [date] order by id) as rn -- For each name/date combination display first record with lowest id
    from #temp -- replace with your table name
)
select
    [date],
    name,
    split,
    id
from cte
where
    split = 1
    and rn = 1
-- End
drop table #temp
```

Comment: That seem to half work but is it now dropping any value with the same details so see how the harry potter value is in twice it should only return 2 records not 4

Comment: row_number() over(partition by name, date order by (select null)) as rn

This might be what you actually want.

Answer (score 1):

If the ID you are interested in is always the lowest ID,  then

```
SELECT Date, Name, Split, MIN(ID) 
FROM log
GROUP BY Date, Name, Split
```

Updating answer for new table question.

```
SELECT Date, Name, Split, MIN(ID) as ID
INTO tablename
FROM log
GROUP BY Date, Name, Split
```

Comment: How do i put the query data in to a new table?

Comment: Updated my answer to create a new table with the results. And a hash(#)  before the table name to make it a temp table.

Comment: An object or column name is missing or empty. For SELECT INTO statements, verify each column has a name. For other statements, look for empty alias names. Aliases defined as "" or [] are not allowed. Change the alias to a valid name.

Comment: The min(id) column needed an alias. Updated answer.